# Relative clause after three times

Tags: relative-clauses

> You have to brush your teeth for your health three times which are in the morning,afternoon and evening.

''three times'' is used as an adverb in this sentence. Can use relative clause in the way above ?

Comment: 'Three times _a day_ ' would be clearer.

Comment: I don't think you can use a relative clause here. The *simplest* way to say it might be: "To stay healthy your teeth need to be brushed three times a day: in the morning, the afternoon and the evening." I can't see a place for "which" (or "that", or "who"), unless it is this: "To stay healthy you need to look after your teeth, which need to be brushed in the morning, the afternoon and the evening." [By the way, I'm not sure if you are talking about your teeth's health or your general health. My first suggestion implies **their** health: my second, **yours**.]